# Manipulating regex match in replace

Tags: regex, perl

I want to add brackets to the first sub-string which matches the regular expression. I am trying to achieve that by using the `$1` variable however I get an error when trying to compile.

Where is my mistake, is there a more convenient way to get your hands on the value of the match?

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Hello world!\n";
my $str = "a aa";

$str =~ s/a/\($1\)/;
print "$str \n";
```

Error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string 
     at /home/bc/projects/regex.pl line 8.
```

Output should be:

```
(a) aa
```

Comment: I edited out the "basic" disclaimer. This is a good question (you did the work, you posted the code you tried, you posted expected output and the error); there's - at least not supposed to be - no stigma to "simple" or "basic" questions as long as they are as high quality as yours.

Comment: Thanks, and I agree the disclaimer doesn't really have place here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [capturing parens](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches) in the regex:

```
$str =~ s/(a)/($1)/;
```

Note: You do not need to escape regular expression special characters like parenthesis in the RHS (right hand side) of a `s///`.

Comment: Nice, that is what I was looking for. I will accept this as an answer once the timer expires.